# summation for multiple columns dynamically

Tags: r

Hi I have dataframe with multiple columns ,I.e first 5 columns are my metadata and remaing 
columns (columns count will be even) are actual columns which need to be calculated

formula : (col6*col9) + (col7*col10) + (col8*col11)

```
country<-c("US","US","US","US")
name <-c("A","B","c","d")
dob<-c(2017,2018,2018,2010)
day<-c(1,4,7,9)
hour<-c(10,11,2,4)
a <-c(1,3,4,5)
d<-c(1,9,4,0)
e<-c(8,1,0,7)
f<-c(10,2,5,6)
j<-c(1,4,2,7)
m<-c(1,5,7,1)
df=data.frame(country,name,dob,day,hour,a,d,e,f,j,m)
```

how to get final summation if i have more columns

I have tried with below code

```
df$final <-(df$a*df$f)+(df$d*df$j)+(df$e*df$m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do generalize the computation:

```
x <- ncol(df) - 5
df$final <- rowSums(df[6:(5 + x/2)] * df[(ncol(df) - x/2 + 1):ncol(df)])

#   country name  dob day hour a d e  f j m final
# 1      US    A 2017   1   10 1 1 8 10 1 1    19
# 2      US    B 2018   4   11 3 9 1  2 4 5    47
# 3      US    c 2018   7    2 4 4 0  5 2 7    28
# 4      US    d 2010   9    4 5 0 7  6 7 1    37
```